# Multiplying SparseArray by negative number Crashes Kernel

Tags: matrix, bugs, sparse-arrays, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0**

---

Can anyone reproduce the following bug, or figure out a work-around.  The following crashes the kernel on both Mathematica 10 and 11, on my macs, running OSX 10.10 and 10.11:

```
Cl[len_Integer] := SparseArray[{
  Band[{1, 1}] -> Table[-2., {len}],
  Band[{1, 2}] -> Table[1. + 1./(2 j - 1.), {j, 1., len - 1}],
  Band[{2, 1}] -> Table[1. - 1./(2 j + 1.), {j, 1., len - 1}]}, 
  {len, len}]

s = Cl[30]

t = -2. s
```

The last line (simply multiplying the matrix by a negative number) causes the crash.  I have tried changing the matrix -- and some changes help, other do not.  Multiplying by positive numbers is fine.

Comment: It works on *Mathematica* 10 for windows.

Comment: It works fine on v10.0.1 on a Mac. Do you possibly have some lingering definitions? Have you tried quitting the kernel and evaluating just these cells?

Comment: Happens to me as well... `-2. s`  crashes the kernel. Mac 10.11.6, Mathematica 11.0.1

Comment: Works with no problems on `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: We're investigating it.

Comment: Works here, OS X 10.11.6, Mathematica 11.0.0

Comment: Workaround: [turn off](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406) the Suggestions bar.

Comment: Thanks -- turning off the Suggestions bar indeed eliminated the issue.

Comment: Please indicate the exact versions you tested, and update the question.  Always use all three components of the version number, e.g. 10.0.2 or 11.0.1.

Comment: I reproduced it in 9.0.1 on OS X, which I think introduced the suggestions bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug.  From @ilian's comment:

> Workaround: [turn off](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406) the Suggestions bar.